# Can anybody help me with limiting an html buttons border to a certain length?

Tags: html, css, button

This is the (wrong) code for it:

```css
.btn-group .button {
  background-color: #fffff1;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  color: #3c4043;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
}

.button1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.btn-group .button:not(:last-child) {
  
}

.btn-group .button:hover {
  background-color: #fffff1;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 0px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="button button1">Button</button>
  <button class="button button2">Button</button>
  <button class="button button3">Button</button>
  <button class="button button4">Button</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The required result ( the image is photoshopped ) :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BttFk.png)
( help  me please )

im trying to limit the border on the butttons length to a certain size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pseudo element `after` to make this work. Here are the changes i made that you should be weary of:

```
.button {
  background-color: salmon /* so you can see the changes easier */
  position: relative /* this is so we can anchor the :after element */
}
.button:after {
  content: "";
  background: black;

  /* so we can adjust the position of the border bottom */
  position: absolute;

  /* bottom: 0 is to put it at the bottom*/
  bottom: 0;

  /* left: 5% is to center it */
  left: 5%;

  height: 1px;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```css
.btn-group .button {
  /* background-color: #fffff1; */
  background-color: salmon;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #3c4043;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-group .button:after {
  content: "";
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5%;
  height: 1px;
  width: 90%;
}

.btn-group .button:hover {
  background-color: #fffff1;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 0px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="button button1">Button</button>
  <button class="button button2">Button</button>
  <button class="button button3">Button</button>
  <button class="button button4">Button</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using pseudo elements. Here is the code:

```css
.btn-group .button {
  background-color: #fffff1;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
 /* border-bottom: 1px solid black;*/
  color: #3c4043;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
}

.button {
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.button::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.button1 {
 /* border-bottom: 1px solid black;*/
}

.btn-group .button:not(:last-child) {
  
}

.btn-group .button:hover {
  background-color: #fffff1;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 0px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="button button1">Button</button>
  <button class="button button2">Button</button>
  <button class="button button3">Button</button>
  <button class="button button4">Button</button>
  <button class="button button4">Button</button>
  <button class="button button4">Button</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could set a max width to your button. That would restrict the border only to the width you define.

```
.btn-group .button{
    max-width: 20px;
}
```

You can put any value, 20px is just a random value you can adjust according to your own needs.

Comment: this does not work, the border bottom is still curving up to the side border.

Comment: @shreyas The border is "curving up to the side" because there is `border-radius`.

Comment: Right sorry I misunderstood your question, try removing 'radius'.